# Design advice for handling different protocol sessions types

Tags: java, .net, spring, oop, architecture

i am trying to think about plug-ability and maintainability structure for handling sessions in the server side. I am sure this issue was raised in many places to any services givers.

Session can be of different protocols: HTTP, Webservice, ProtocolX, ProtocolY.

So basically each session type will be different by the protocol it implements.

Each session will "speak" with the server with it's own protocol but the rest of the logic will be the same(for example authenticate the client against the DB.. etc etc)

So of course i thought right away of having session adapters layer and "sessionProtocol interfaces" which will be implemented by each session type.

Anyone could provide and designing suggestionsto put all this things together or any other suggestions? (known Design pattern for this case would be warmly welcomed as well).

thanks,
ray.

Comment: I don't think I understand, can you provide an example of what you are trying to achieve? on the face of things it seems a bit weird that you are trying to sync browser sessions with JMS sessions.

Comment: It's not necessary browser sessions. more about different protocols. anyway I took the JMS off from the list coz jms is not protocol but API.